'The workspace contains Java Projects, would you like to import them?' Prompt is not displayed
I cloned a repository from Github and opened it in VS code, however, I am not getting the aforementioned prompt so I think VS code is unable to recognize my Java files. Now if I were to run and debug the code, I'd receive the following error:                                                    Error: Could not find or load main class firstExamples.FirstExample
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: firstExamples.FirstExample
So far I have tried cleaning the java workspace and reloading the project as well as re-downloading the Java extension pack but I still face the same problems unfortunately. Any help would be greatly appreciated
